# Supported Reporting Intervals for Microsoft Band 2

Tags: c#, microsoft-band

Band 1 allows setting reporting intervals for sensor readings.

Now band 2, looks like it has only one supported reading interval and it cannot be changed. Does anyone know:

1. The allowed supported reporting intervals for each sensor on the Microsoft Band?
2. How to change the reporting interval?

So far, as an example, I have the following code:

```
this.bandClient.SensorManager.Altimeter.ReadingChanged += this.OnAltimeterReadingChanged;

//bandClient.SensorManager.Altimeter.ReportingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);

//get a list of available reporting intervals
IEnumerable<TimeSpan> supportedAltimeterReportingIntervals =bandClient.SensorManager.Altimeter.SupportedReportingIntervals;

foreach (var ri in supportedAltimeterReportingIntervals)
{
     Debug.WriteLine("Altimeter Reporting Interval is {0}", ri.ToString());
}
```

This line:

```
//bandClient.SensorManager.Altimeter.ReportingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
```

Returns:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in
>   Microsoft.Band.ni.DLL
>
> The enumeration of supported reporting intervals, returns:  Altimeter
>   Reporting Interval is 00:00:00.5000000 (Only 1 interval)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each sensor on the Band has its own set of supported reporting intervals (and sometimes only a single supported interval).  Neither that nor the way in which reporting intervals are set has changed between Band 1 and 2.  (Band 2 adds new sensors, such as the altimeter, that did not exist in Band 1.)

Regarding question #1, you can find information about each of the sensors in the [documentation](http://developer.microsofthealth.com/Content/docs/Microsoft%20Band%20SDK.pdf) at the [Microsoft Health development site](http://developer.microsofthealth.com).  (Curiously, they list the altimeter as being 1Hz, but the SDK is apparently returning 2Hz as the reporting interval.)

Regarding question #2, you set the reporting interval using the `IBandSensor.ReportingInterval = <TimeSpan>` where the `TimeSpan` is one of the values from `IBandSensor.SupportedReportingIntervals`.

In your example code, you were attempting to set the altimeter sensor to report at an unsupported interval, which is why you see the exception.

Comment: just found the frequencies on page 4. Thank you so much!